# Insert JournalType DUPLICATE_VALUE exception in Loyalty cloud test class

Tags: unit-test, dmlexception, duplicate-value

We are working with **Salesforce Loyalty cloud**. In one of our test classes, we are setting up data, where we try to insert some records of the `JournalType` standard object coming with Loyalty cloud.

However we are unable to insert any, since we face a DML exception due to `DUPLICATE_VALUE`. It is weird since we are not using `@TestSetup` nor `SeeAllData=true`.

```
@isTest
private class LM_CalculatePointsTest {
        
        @isTest(SeeAllData=false)     
        static void SeeAllDataFalseTest() {
            List<JournalType> jTypes = [SELECT Id, Name FROM JournalType];
    
            System.debug('Journal Types => ' + JSON.serializePretty(jTypes)); // Output: DEBUG|Journal Types => [ ]
    
            JournalType jt = new JournalType(Name = 'Accrual');
    
            Database.insert(jt); // throws: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, A journal type with this name already exists.: [Name]
        }
}
```

How is this even possible?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that it is a SF known issue, which is going to have a fix in the next release.

However, I also spotted other problems:

We have set of unit tests testing functionality around Loyalty Management. We were facing issues recently with execution of these tests and as workaround we were implementing unique names for each `LoyaltyProgram` this workaround fixed unit tests if we are executing them one by one in Dev environment. However we are facing issue if we are trying to deploy them to other environment, CI in our case. All tests are failing on :

> Internal Salesforce Error: 174353001-109788 (-1847234888)
> (-1847234888) Stack Trace: null

Even with dummy deployment validation ( so no real code change is introduced during it ) tests are still failing on Internal Salesforce Error

Curiosity is that if tests are executed in the same environment via console they are passing. But executed in deployment they are failing.

What all failing tests have in common is that they are working with  `LoyaltyProgram`.

Comment: Did you ever confirm that this JournalType issue was fixed in 2022? We're currently running into this issue. Gotta love features that use records as core configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems like an issue of Loyalty Management. There is workaround for it, please check: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002aMmsQAE&_ga=2.87831384.1731144651.1655108264-1315708974.1653923732

You need to implement random string (date time in this solution) for name of Loyalty Program. But be super careful implementing it, from my experience you need to create all object manually to make it work. If you are creating your data form static resources you will need to rework it so it will be created from scratch.
Note that any update or any kind of change into Loyalty data in runtime of Test will break test with InternalServerError.

For JournalType i would try the same approach with random name.

Salesforce Support confirmed that they have this issue fixed and fix will be released this September